# Java nextDouble() blank value

Tags: java, null, java.util.scanner

I have my constructor with the conditions that if it finds a blank (null) value continues with the program. But does nothing:

```
public Cuenta(Double cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        if (cantidad>=0){
            System.out.print("El saldo de su cuenta es "+cantidad+"\n");
        }
        if (Objects.equals(cantidad, "")) {

        }
    }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner cta = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.print("Ingrese el saldo de su cuenta \n");
   Cuenta cantidad = new Cuenta(cta.nextDouble());

    }
```

Comment: `if (Objects.equals(cantidad, ""))` will always fail (Double is never String("")). And please explain or translate texts so we can understand the meaning.

Comment: The `nextXxx()` calls of `Scanner` doesn't return empty strings, since the default is for `nextXxx()` methods to scan the next *token*, i.e. characters surrounded by whitespace. If you want to support user pressing Enter without typing anything, you need to use `nextLine()`, check for empty string, then parse the `Double` value yourself if not empty.

Comment: @SynchroDynamic Except that `cta.nextDouble()` returns `double`, not `Double`, so the value will never *be* null.

Comment: `public Account(Double quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        if (quantity>=0){
            System.out.print("The balance of your account is "+quantity+"\n");
        }
        if (Objects.equals(quantity, "")) {

        }
    }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner cta = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.print("Add the balance of your account \n");
   Account quantity = new Account(cta.nextDouble());

    }`